# How to make the notification manager not get the times in past?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, notify, notificationmanager

I don't know if the title clear or not, my problem with the notification manager is that when I set the times as ( 1:00 , 2:00 , 3:00 , 4:00) and the time now is 2:30, the normal notification will wait until 3:00 then 4:00 ,, but in my code the notification manager give me two alert for 1:00 and 2:00 because the are in past , then wait until 3:00 and notify then 4:00 and notify, so my problem is with the times in past I don't want to get notification for them.

my code
Main class.java , alertTimes is an array that have the times in millisecond

```
  for (int i = 0; i < alertTimes.length; i++) {
            inte = new Intent(this, AlertMedicine.class);
            inte.putExtra("id", i);
            inte.putExtra("name", NameOftimes[i]);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTimes[i], PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, inte, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        }
```

AlertReceiver.java

```
 createNotification(context, "OK", "OK", "OK" + j, 1, 0);
```

I also try in AlertReceiver.java to do this but this also not work

```
if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)< Integer.parseInt(arr[id].substring(0, 2))) {
           createNotification(context, "OK", "OK", "OK" + j, 1, 0);

       }
        else
       if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)== Integer.parseInt(arr[id].substring(0, 2))){

           int min=Integer.parseInt(arr[id].substring(3, 5))+2;
           if(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) <= min){
               createNotification(context, "OK", "OK", "OK" + j, 1, 0);
```

Comment: For kicks, what happens when you switch the evaluation of the current HOUR_OF_DAY to the time you're checking to greater than?

Comment: it does not give me the next first notification, as in my example ( 1:00 , 2:00 , 3:00 , 4:00)  and the time is 2:30 , it will not give me 3:00 notify, it will wait until 4:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should schedule the alarms for future time only because `set()` will trigger the alarm immediately if the stated trigger time is in the past. 
See the doc below :

> public void set (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent
>   operation) Added in API level 1
>
> Schedule an alarm. Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc)
>   it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. If there is
>   already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, that previous
>   alarm will first be canceled. If the stated trigger time is in the
>   past, the alarm will be triggered immediately. If there is already an
>   alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents
>   being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and
>   replaced by this one.

So, to fix your issue check if the alarm time you need to set is in future or not, then only set it otherwise ignore,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < alertTimes.length; i++) {
        if( alertTimes[i] >= System.currentTimeMillis()){

                inte = new Intent(this, AlertMedicine.class);
                inte.putExtra("id", i);
                inte.putExtra("name", NameOftimes[i]);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTimes[i], PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i+1, inte, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        }
    }
```

Comment: but its just give me the first notification from the loop, do  you know how to fix it? it seems like its does not go in the loop for all the times :(

Comment: please if you can help me

Comment: You need to change the request code every time in PendingIntent.getBroadcast().  Edited the answer.